# Weird discrepancy between database value and value display in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I've implemented a voting system, and in my view where I print `video.vote_sum`, the value for one of the video's vote_sum displays 1. However when I run `Video.find(450)` in my console, I see that the element actually has a vote_sum of two. I'm not sure why this is happening, and although the voting works as it should, when I reload the page, the `pluralize` method in my view displays "1 votes". But this is only upon a page reload. When I'm voting, it displays "1 vote". Weird.

Here's the create method in the video_votes controller:

```
def create       
  @video = Video.find(params[:video_id])
  @vote = current_user.video_votes.find_or_create_by_video_id(@video.id)

  if @vote.value.nil?
    if params[:type] == "up"
      @vote.value = 1
    else
      @vote.value = -1
    end
  elsif (params[:type] == "up" && @vote.value == 1) || (params[:type] == "down" && @vote.value == -1)
    @vote.value = 0
  elsif ((params[:type] == "up" && @vote.value == -1) || (params[:type] == "down" && @vote.value == 1)) || (@vote.value == 0)
    if params[:type] == "up"
      @vote.value = 1
    else
      @vote.value = -1
    end
  end  

  if @vote.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @video }
      format.js
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @video }
      format.js {render 'fail_create.js.erb'}
    end
  end  
end
```

Here's the relevant code in my Video model:

```
def vote_sum
  video_votes.sum(:value)
end
```

And here's the relevant code in my video_vote model:

```
after_update :update_vote_sum

private

  def update_vote_sum
    video.update_attributes!(:vote_sum => video.vote_sum + value)
  end
```

Why is this happening, and how could I fix it?

Comment: How You could have to calculate `vote_sum` in `Video` if you have a model field of this name ? you should switch to only one way of calculating the votes - right now You do update it once from `video_vote` `after_update` and second recalculate in `Video.vote_sum` - that could be only trouble.

Comment: hmmm, then how should I fix that?

Comment: first try toy remove `def vote_sum` from `Video`, if I got it right then `Video.vote_sum` will be correctly updated with fix in my answer.

Comment: na, removing `vote_sum` messed up the voting system.

Comment: change `after_update` to `after_save`

Comment: should I do that and keep everything else fixed?

Comment: add all my fixes, that keeps to go to give final answer

Comment: then it has to be issue with `after_update` restore `Video` `def vote_sum` and comment out `after_update` keep `@video.reload` in the controller.

Comment: sorry @mpapis, my question details were misleading and the mistake was actually in the view in the pluralize method. Brandon solved it. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a problem with your view and the way you're using `pluralize`--you're supposed to pass it the singular version of your noun, and *optionally* a plural version (in case it can't guess it correctly).

Please see [my change on GitHub](https://github.com/BinaryMuse/Dreamstill/commit/5dd93592075a935951b3d0b1b34e266cae2e55ee).

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

[Update]

After messing with your app, somehow it's possible to get `video.vote_sum` (the actual database value) to be different than `video.video_votes.sum(:value)`; I'm not yet sure why. However, you do have another issue with your codebase, demonstrated below:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > v = Video.find 2
 => #<Video id: 2, ... video_votes_count: 0, vote_sum: 3> 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 > v.video_votes.sum(:value)
 => 2 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :003 > v.vote_sum
 => 2 # doesn't match vote_sum in the database!
```

**You have a method called `vote_sum` on your `Video` model.** This means when you access `@video.vote_sum`, you are NOT accessing the `vote_sum` property from the model from the database, because you overwrite that functionality. This makes it pointless to update `vote_sum` in `VideoVote`'s `after_create` because you can never access it (as demonstrated in my IRB session, above).

Answer (score 0):

You should to reload the video:

```
if @vote.save
  @video.reload
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @video }
```

There might be other way to reload `vote_sum` only without reloading `@video` but this should be quite enough for the start.

---

Also please note you could have a better use of model `:counter_cache` when you would separate `up` and `down` votes to separate relation/models ... it's sad but sometimes to get full power of rails you need to make freaky things with your models.

Comment: I don't understand, why do I need to do this?

Comment: cause you loaded `@video` before updating it's `vote_sum`, when you want to get the current `vote_sum` you need to reload `@video`

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue :/